# The effect of the position of the control variable on the loop body

Tags: c, string

error

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char *str = " H  el l  o, Wor   ld   ";
    char del_space[256] = "\0";
    printf("%s\n",str);
    for (size_t i = 0;str[i] != '\0';++i)
    {
        size_t j = 0;
        if (str[i] != ' ')
        {
            del_space[j] = str[i];
            ++j;
        }
    }
    printf("%s",del_space);
    return 0;
}
```

correct

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char *str = " H  el l  o, Wor   ld   ";
    char del_space[256] = "\0";
    printf("%s\n",str);
    for (size_t i = 0,j = 0;str[i] != '\0';++i)
    {
        if (str[i] != ' ')
        {
            del_space[j] = str[i];
            ++j;
        }
    }
    printf("%s",del_space);
    return 0;
}
```

Why is the first way wrong and the second way right? I just moved the position of a control variable, but the value of *del_space* in the first way is wrong? The compiler I use is GCC8.2.3 .Is there any special reason for this?

Comment: Because, in the first example, `j` is reset to zero on _every_ loop iteration, so _all_ non-space characters will be put in `del_space[0]` (i.e. the `j++` is [effectively] a no-op). The final string will have only _one_ non-space char [if `str` has any non-space char].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first one sets `j = 0`each time through the loop. The second one only sets `j=0` once - the first time through the loop.

Comment: It is the other way around.

Comment: @TheDark true. Fixed now :-)